# A polynomial function has degree 3 and a positive lead coefficient. Which graph could represent the function? *

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[image]

A polynomial function has degree 3 and a positive lead coefficient. Which graph could represent the function? *

Comment: The leading (first) term is $ \ ax^3 \ $ with $ \ a \ > \ 0 \ $ .  Start by eliminating the curves that _can't_ be right.

Answer (score 1):

How does it behave for large x?

How many roots can it have?

Comment: Also, how many "turning points" can such a polynomial possibly have?